# Playing multiple wav files in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, wav

I have an app that I need to play a wav file when a key or button pressed or clicked, I use the SoundPlayer class but when i try to play another wav file at the same time the one that was playing stops.

Is there a way to play multiple wav files at the same time?
If its one could you please give me examples or tutorial?

Here's what I got so far:

```
private void pictureBox20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (label30.Text == "Waiting 15.wav")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No beat loaded");
        return;
    }
    using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(label51.Text))
    {
        try
        {
            player.Play();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File has been moved." + "\n" + "Please relocate it now!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your existing code please? You can do that by clicking [edit]. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms program?

Comment: Uhm i for got that, edited.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with the [`System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.aspx) class. Note that you will need to add references to `WindowsBase` and `PresentationCore`.

```
private void pictureBox20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const bool loopPlayer = true;
    if (label30.Text == "Waiting 15.wav")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No beat loaded");
        return;
    }
    var player = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
    try
    {
        player.Open(new Uri(label51.Text));
        if(loopPlayer)
            player.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_Loop;
        player.Play();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File has been moved." + "\n" + "Please relocate it now!");
    }
}
```

EDIT: You can loop the sound by subscribing to the `MediaEnded` event.

```
void MediaPlayer_Loop(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MediaPlayer player = sender as MediaPlayer;
    if (player == null)
        return;

    player.Position = new TimeSpan(0);
    player.Play();
}
```

Based on your code, I'm guessing that you are writing some kind of music production software. I'm honestly not sure that this method will loop perfectly every time, but as far as I can tell, it's the only way to loop using the MediaPlayer control.

Comment: Thanks, can you also use looping using this method? If possible how? Thanks!

Comment: @JoseCardama You can use the MediaEnded event to loop the sound. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you, I really apreciate your help. (To stop i just make "player.Stop();"?)

Comment: Hi again the loop and play/stop is working just fine. Now I need to control the volume with a track bar. Could you please show me how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set the volume using [`MediaPlayer.Volume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.volume.aspx). Note that Volume is a double between 0 and 1, so you would want something like `player.Volume = (double)trackBar.Value / trackBar.Maximum`.

Answer (score 0):

#### You **cannot** play two sounds at once using SoundPlayer.

SoundPlayer uses the Native WINAPI [`PlaySound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757715%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which does not support playing multiple sound at same instance.

Better Option would be to Reference `WindowsMediaPlayer`

Add a reference to `C:\Windows\System32\wmp.dll`

```
var player1 = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
player1.URL = @"C:\audio_output\sample1.wav";

var player2 = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
player2.URL = @"C:\audio_output\sample2.wav";
```